# How to obtain object references when using declarative Dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, declarative

I'd like to know how to get an object reference when using Dojo with declarative HTML.

I have some code for sliding panel that I took from an example: http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileSlideShow/demo.html

In my version there are navigation buttons. dojox.Mobile.SwapView has a goTo method, which I should be able to use, but I can't figure out how to get the object reference I need to call the method from. In the example below, the object would be 'ref' - how can I obtain this reference?

```
<div class="panel" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.SwapView">
  <p>Some text..</p>
  <div class="next" onclick="ref.goTo(1)">Next</div>
</div>
<div class="panel" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.SwapView">
  <p>Some other text..</p>
  <div class="prev" onclick="ref.goTo(-1)">Prev</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
onclick="dijit.registry.byNode(this.parentNode).goTo(1)"
```

or

```
onclick="dojo.publish('/dojox/mobile/prevPage', dijit.registry.byNode(this.parentNode))"
```

Not sure if there is a cleaner way

Comment: Thanks, that worked. My actual document structure is more complicated, so I changed it to: dijit.registry.byNode(dojo.byId('panel-1')).goTo(1)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, an additional option would be the use of the "data-dojo-id" property.  You add this to your declaration which will then create a global variable with the name supplied.  This  variable will be set to a reference to the declared widget.

For example:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.SwapView" data-dojo-id="view1">
```

will create a variable called `view1` that will hold a reference to the SwapView.